# How to add the position of each character of the word in a list

Tags: java, list, char, position

I'm trying to add the position of each character of the word in my list. 
Each line contains a character, \t and a number. The words are separated by the character "x". And, I must ignore the character "z".

My input is an ArrayList.

Example:

ArrayList (input) :

```
x  0
T  0
h  0
e  0
x  0
b  1
z  0
o  0
y  0
```

The output should be :

```
x  0
T  1  0
h  2  0
e  3  0
x  0
b  1  1
z  0
o  2  0
y  3  0
```

My output

```
x  0  0
T  0  0
h  0  0
e  0  0
x  0  0
b  1  0
z  0  0
o  0  0
y  0  0
```

My code

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    if ((list.get(i)).startsWith("x")) {
        j++;
        while ((!(list.get(i)).startsWith("z")) && (j != 0)) {
            if ((list.get(i)).endsWith("\t1")) {
                list.set(i, (list.get(i)).replace("\t1", "\t" + j + "\t1"));
                j++;
            } else if ((list.get(i)).endsWith("\t0")) {
                list.set(i, (list.get(i)).replace("\t0", "\t" + j + "\t0"));
                j++;
            }
            if ("x".equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, what is the input ? edit your post and clarify it ;)

Comment: @azro I edited the post. my input is an ArrayList where each line contains a Char then tabulation then an Int (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that i have understood your problem. Here is solution:
word is your input ArrayList

```
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        String current = word.get(i);
        if (current.charAt(0) == 'z') {
            result.add(current.charAt(0) + "\t" + 0 + "\t" );
        } else if (current.charAt(0) == 'x') {
            counter = 1;
            result.add(current.charAt(0) + "\t" + 0 + "\t");
        }  else {
            result.add(current.charAt(0) + "\t" + counter + "\t" + current.charAt(current.length()-1));
            counter++;
        }
```

printed result List will be:

```
x   0   
T   1   0
h   2   0
e   3   0
x   0   
b   1   1
z   0   
o   2   0
y   3   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I don't have "searchedWord", I only have the ArrayList.